# stackoverflow: save theme preference

Tags: browser, themes

Suddenly today stackoverflow looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The blue color is undesired.

I tried to change the theme under settings. The theme is correctly applied, but I don't see a way to save it: As soon as I leave the settings page, the blue colors are back.

What can I do to get to permanently revert to the default look?

**UPDATE**

Could this be a virus? Heres' what I get on Safari:

[image]

I'm on MacOS Monterey. The first screenshot is on Firefox, the second screenshot on Safari. Chrome also gives different colors.

Comment: I'm seeing different colors on firefox, chrome and safari. On safari, the colors are wild. Could this be some sort of virus?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the "FILTERS" bar at the bottom of your screen, click on the "circle with slash" icon. It will revert your screen to the default view.

Comment: Used to select theme, but now the theme selection not shows?

Answer (score 2):

Check the date. It's April fool's day.

Comment: Oh wow. It's not yet here, still 31 March.

Comment: i don't see how it's an April Foole's joke.... maybe mischievous... however.. the answer from @digital_buddha was correct and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The way you fix it is you click on your profile picture in the top, then you go to settings, and then you can choose your background. It probably isn't a virus, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks WolfGirl, so that's what I've tried. Maybe it's an April Fool's joke?